# angularjs ng-click and href on anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

If there's an ng-click and a href together on an anchor the ng-click doesn't work. I want both to work if possible, go to a route and then run a function. My use-case is I have a drawer open with a panel of links, when going to a link I want to close the drawer.

What's an easy way to get both working at the same time?

Comment: you can either redirect using href of use ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was asking for the wrong thing. Using the href and the ng-click together works perfectly fine, I just had an ui-view in the parent element that prevented any angular bindings from working at all.

Comment: Is ui-view an Angular directive?

Comment: @Weiming - Yes, ui-view belongs to uiRouter: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 6):

Once you navigate away from the page scripts no longer run.*

Your flow can be something like:

When the user clicks, run a function that does the following:

- Run the original function you wanted to run
- Handle any 'navigate away in this specific case' logic.
- Change `location.href` to the URL you want to to navigate to.

It's of course possible to extract this behavior to a directive if you find yourself implementing that bit of logic over and over :)

* <sup>You can use onbeforeunload but that's not good for plenty of other reasons</sup>