# Href is not working with ng-click in <a> tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to use href and ng-click in a tag.

```
<a href="#/home" ng-click="ctl.modify()"> </a>
```

When I use href and ng-click in a tag, ng-click is working but href is not working.

Please let me know how to make href work?

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717072/angularjs-ng-click-and-href-on-anchor

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-href` here with anchor tag. [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/atTEvb2K8ZrEus9nqOsS?p=preview)

```
  <a ng-href="#/home" ng-click="ctl.modify()"> </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried with ng-href it didn't worked :-( .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

HTML code:

```
   <a ng-click="go('/home')"></a>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
  $location.path( path );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I am in \home page and i want reload the same (\home) page with ng-click, $location.path(path) is not reloading the same page. So , i tried with $route.reload(); it worked :-) .

Comment: ohh okay.  that's nice.. :) @mahi244

Answer (score 0):

In your `ctl.modify()` function you have to add this row:

```
$location.path('/home');
```

Don't forget to add $location as a dependency in the controller params.